# Beginner Java Loops

Tags: java, loops

I have an assignment I'm struggling with quite a bit here. It's an assignment based on loops, which are a little blurry to me. The assignment is as follows:

1. Ask the student name.
2. Ask the course name (cannot be less than 0 --> if so, error message.)
3. Ask how many assignments they submitted.
4. Based on #3, ask a few questions such as total points possible and earned to generate a progress report.

I'm not struggling with anything besides the beginning part of #4. I am not entirely sure how to create a loop that runs for as many assignments that were submitted?

This is what I have so far, I'm mostly struggling with the loop that repeats based on how many assignments were submitted...I tried, I just can't figure it out! I'm pretty confident I can do the rest :)

```
String studentName = " ";
String courseName = " ";
int assign = 0;
int loop = 0;
int totalScore = 0;
int scorethisAssign = 0;

System.out.println("Enter student name:");
studentName = input.next();
System.out.println("Enter course name:");
courseName = input.next();

System.out.println("How many assignments have you submitted:");
assign = input.nextInt();

while (assign <= 0) {
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("You must enter a number greater than 0 -- TRY AGAIN!");
    System.out.println("How many assignments have you submitted:");
    assign = input.nextInt();
}

while (assign > loop);
{
    System.out.println("How many points was assignment "loop + "worth:");
    scorethisAssign = input.nextInt();
    totalScore = scorethisAssign + totalScore;
    loop++;
}
```

This is essentially what the program would output to:

```
Enter student name: Prince Harry
Enter course name: Intro to College Life

How many assignments have you submitted: 4

How many points was assignment 1 worth: 100
How many points did you score: 45

How many points was assignment 2 worth: 75
How many points did you score: 46

How many points was assignment 3 worth: 100
How many points did you score: 83

How many points was assignment 4 worth: 100
How many points did you score: 74


Progress Report for Prince Harry
    Course Name is Intro to College Life
-------------------------------------------------

Number of assignments submitted.....4
Total points possible...............375.00
Total points earned.................248.00
Total percent to date...............66.13%
Letter grade to date................D

-------------------------------------------------

Enter yes if there is another class you want to calculate: no
```

Comment: Can't you see I literally did as much as possible? I just need help with ONE SMALL PART OF IT..I'm not asking someone to do it.

Comment: Why are `assign` and `loop` doubles?  You don't need the extra precision; you could use `int` instead.

Comment: @Makato Yeah, whoops! Silly mistake - changing that now! I'm fairly new to Java.

Comment: You've got almost all of it already.  You're missing a + sign in that last message, and you're starting your `loop` variable at 0 rather than 1.  But I don't think either of those is insurmountable.  Which bit are you actually stuck with?

Comment: Outside of the mysterious case of the `double`,  you're pretty much 99% there.  You'd need to provide the questions to the end user and use `print` instead of `println` where appropriate, of course.  What is the crucial portion you're stuck on?  Is it getting the total to print at the bottom?

Comment: Please don't edit the question to accommodate people's suggestions - it makes the question into nonsense, and it's not helpful to future people who might be having similar difficulties.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: this is a perfectly legitimate homework question. I'm usually the first to jump down student's throats when they ask us to do their homework for them, but this poster has clearly put in effort and isn't looking for a handout.

Comment: `while` will work, but I'd consider the pros and cons of using `for` in this case instead.

Comment: @DavidWallace When I run the program, and get to "how many assignments were submitted" it doesn't follow past it. For example, if I hit 3 assignments submitted nothing happens. I assumed something was wrong with my loop...

Comment: @musical_coder Thank you, I appreciate that very much! I was a little frustrated by his comment (almost as much as Loops! Hah!)

Comment: That might be because you've used `next()` instead of `nextLine()` in the previous calls to your `Scanner`, which by default fetches a single word.  I suggest you use a debugger to check out whether the values of `studentName` and `courseName` are what you expect at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `;` at the end of `while(assign > loop)`, otherwise you're going to have an infinite loop there.

Answer (score 1):

I would say a `for` loop for your assignment checking is better readable and probably will give you less of hassles. Since you have `assign` being the number of assignments, you could use that variable to annotate each assignment in your `for` loop.
Besides, your current solution seems to work as well.

[Java 'for' statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)